# Angular: Default handler for unhandled http errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, error-handling, promise

In my angularjs app, I defined a default handler for http errors this way:

```
myapp.config([ '$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('errorInterceptor')
}])
```

where `errorInterceptor` is a service that displays some details about the error in an alert field on the top of the current page.

Now, when I want to handle a specific error in a different way (say the query is triggered in a modal, and I want to display the alert only in this modal, and not at page level):

```
$http.get('/my/request').then(success, specificErrorHandling)
```

Angular does the `specificErrorHandling` but still triggers my `errorInterceptor`, so my error gets reported twice. Is there a way to avoid that?

More generically, is there an Angular way to handle only errors that aren't already taken care of along the `promise` chain, the same way the top-level error handler of a server app doesn't have to handle catched exceptions?

**Edit:** As requested by Beetroot-Beetroot in comments, here is the code for my interceptor:

```
@app.factory 'errorInterceptor', [ '$q', 'alertsHandler',
  ($q, alertsHandler) ->
    success = (response) ->
      response

    failure = (response) ->
        alertsHandler.raise(response)

    (promise) ->
      promise.then success, failure
]
```

Comment: Can you post a (simplified version of) errorInterceptor please.

Comment: I think showing the alerts from interceptor its a not so good idea,  and I think there is a no way achieve that (may be I'm wrong)

Comment: What specifically is done with the error is not the important part. It's really about having a default error handling, so you don't have to implement a specific error handler for 100% of async calls, and being able to defuse it when you do implement a specific handling. Much like exceptions. Is there a better way to implement a default error handler than an interceptor?

Answer (score 5):

We have something like that.

If we handle the http error, we pass a property on the request called `errorHandled:true`

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/my/url',
    errorHandled:true
}).then(function(){ ... }, function(){ ... });
```

And then in the intercept for `responseError: function(rejection){ ... }` we can see if this flag is set by looking at `rejection.config.errorHandled` and if not - then we pop a toastr dialog with the error. the code looks something like this

```
function ( rejection ) { 
    if ( !rejection.config.errorHandled && rejection.data.message ){
        toastr.error(rejection.data.message, 'Error');
    }
    return $q.reject(rejection); 
}
```

The chances of someone writing "errorHandled:true" without adding a handler are slim. The chances of having 2 error indicators are also slim because we got used to it - but actually 2 indicators are better than none..

It would be great if we had the promise to query it if it has an error handler or not down the `then` chain, but we couldn't find this anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you know which errors needs to be suppressed and which one need to be propagate. Also since the Response interceptor is a function that returns promise itself

You can catch the response for failure case and instead of propagating it up the stack you can return something such as empty response.

If you look at the [sample](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) example in angular documentation for interceptor

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
    return function(promise) {
        return promise.then(function(response) {
            // do something on success
        }, function(response) {
            // do something on error
            if (canRecover(response)) {
                return responseOrNewPromise; // This can suppress the error.
            }
            return $q.reject(response); // This propogates it.
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but this global error handler is executed before all the others and knows what it leaves to the others. What I'm after is the other way around: executed after the others and handling only what they left.

Comment: So you are looking for a common error handler, which can handle all unhandled errors, that runs in the event the calling code does not handle it?

Comment: That's it, a default error handler for when no specific one is defined (sorry about the very late relpy, I had missed yours)